# (C2352) C++ Return value as function default parameter

Tags: c++, function, class, templates, arguments

I'm making a linked list class and I want a convenient default argument for my 'remove()' function.

```cpp
int size() { return size_; }

int remove(int index = size() - 1);
                         ^[C2352]
```

This gives me an error *a call of a non-static member function requires an object*, so I tried

```cpp
int remove(int index = this->size() - 1);
```

However the *this* keyword cannot be used outside of a function.
I want to avoid making *size_* a public variable, for safety reasons.
Note that my class is a template class.

I would appreciate any help for finding a solution for this.

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your given example cannot re-produce the given error.

Comment: Make `size` a `static` member function? That way you won't need an object for using/calling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default arguments must be bound at compile time, so `this` is not allowed since it's a runtime value. You could use a free/static function but I don't see how the design is going to work as it wouldn't refer to any specific list instance.

In my opinion the best solution is to use a special value for what you need, eg:

```
class List
{
  static constexpr int LAST_ELEMENT_INDEX = -1;

  void remove(int index = LAST_ELEMENT_INDEX)
  {
    if (index == LAST_ELEMENT_INDEX)
      index = size() - 1;

    ..
  }
}
```

Comment: This is an alternative solution I had thought of, but not optimal for beauty. However since  a static variable size_ will not work for multiple instances this is the best solution.